buttons not responding in roblox studio
Im making a main menu in Lua(Roblox Studio) and the start game/play button doesnt work
i tried this code for the play button but the button wasnt responding
local button = script.Parent
local main_menu = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
local main_menu_frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent
main_menu.Enabled = true
game.Lighting.Blur.Enabled = true
while true do 
    if button.MouseButton1Click == true then
        game.Lighting.Blur.Enabled = false
        main_menu.Enabled = false
        main_menu_frame.Active = false
        main_menu_frame.Transparency = 1
        main_menu_frame.Visible = false
    end
    task.wait(0.1)
end


Also, Remember that parts of my answer are not needed. For example, you can just say main_menu.visible=false, rather than all the other code. the .visible attributes also set the visibility of all its descendants.

[tag:roblox-studio] is for questions about the IDE, not Roblox programming in general. If this question is about the latter, please [edit] it to use [tag:roblox] instead.

Edit: I confused the bool with the event, my bad!
Connect a function to the event then run your code.
Change your code to:
local button = script.Parent
local main_menu = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
local main_menu_frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent
main_menu.Enabled = true
game.Lighting.Blur.Enabled = true

button.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        game.Lighting.Blur.Enabled = false
        main_menu.Enabled = false
        main_menu_frame.Active = false
        main_menu_frame.Transparency = 1
        main_menu_frame.Visible = false
    
        task.wait(0.1)
        end)

The code you wrote looped while waiting for the button.MouseButton1Click event to finish. This caused an endless loop of the button triggering and then waiting for the loop to finish.
You do not need a loop to check for the event. Instead, just check if the button MouseButton1Down event is triggered then run your code, as the task.wait() function acts as a debounce without the loop.

MouseButton1Click is not a boolean, it's an Event. That means instead of continually checking whether button.MouseButton1Click is true, you should just define a function with the same functionality and bind it to the event in question using the Connect() method.
Additionally, MouseButton1Click is probably the wrong choice here. Activated will perform a similar function, but with more cross-compatibility.
This LocalScript should do the trick:
local button = script.Parent
local main_menu = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
local main_menu_frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent
main_menu.Enabled = true

-- This function defines what should happen when the button gets clicked
local function onClick() 
    game.Lighting.Blur.Enabled = false
    main_menu.Enabled = false
    main_menu_frame.Active = false
    main_menu_frame.Transparency = 1
    main_menu_frame.Visible = false
end

-- And this line ensure the function is called every time the button is activated
button.Activated:Connect(onClick)


@histrueandfalse's comment applies here, too - everything after main_menu.Enabled = false is redundant. But that's not particularly important for this post.

To make Andrew's comment more concise here, you can set the visibility to false, and then set the blur to false. The visibility attribute of all ui elements sets itself and all its' descendants' visibility to false.

this code didnt work maybe it's because i didnt use a local script

@CarlosAranas yea u need a local script

The reason your button isn't responding is that you didn't create an event for the click. Assuming you added a script to a GUI button, then here's the corrected code:
local button = script.Parent
local main_menu = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent
local main_menu_frame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent
main_menu.Enabled = true
game.Lighting.Blur.Enabled = true

button.Clicked:Connect(function()
  --Insert code when the button is clicked here
end)

